# Reading from a file using python & try to write to another file

Tags: python, try-catch

I want to read from `file_1` using Python script & `try` to write it to `file_2`.

More explanation is as below:

`file_1` :Read line is

Actual Transaction is ...----------------------------------------------------------------------
(then almost 100 lines should be printed means entire transaction)

Then, I want to write this transaction in `file_2`.

Can anyone help in the same ?

Comment: Please fix your question, also SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Did you mean copy one file to another ?

Comment: Read [ask] in the same [help].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the content of one file to another file here is the code :

```
with open("file1") as f:
    with open("file2", "w") as f1:
         for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```